# How i can add a new variable to devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using Devise. I would like to add a dynamic var.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_token_authenticatable
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable , :currencies_supported

  def currencies_supported
    Stripe.api_key = access_code
    @currencies_supported = ""
    begin
     last_currency = 'cad'
     all = Stripe::Account.retrieve().currencies_supported
     default_currency = Stripe::Account.retrieve().default_currency
     primary_currencies = [last_currency, default_currency, 'usd', 'eur', 'cad'].uniq

     @currencies_supported = primary_currencies + (all - primary_currencies)

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e

    rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
      p e
    rescue Stripe::AuthenticationError => e
       p e
    rescue Stripe::APIConnectionError => e
       p e
    rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
       p e
    rescue => e
      p e
    end

  end
end
```

I have tried that

> const_get': uninitialized constant Devise::Models::CurrenciesSupported (NameError)
>       from /Users/Michelin/.rvm

Answer (score 0):

This maybe you want,

```
attr_accessor :currencies_supported
```

Remove `:currencies_supported` from `devise`